# setState is not updating while handling events for different listview

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want a single page with different list view. I used styling in setState is not updating for changing different view like grid, large, mid,..

```
var width = Dimensions.get('window').width - 20;
var page = 6;

class FeedUserGrid extends Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 != r2
    });
    this.state = {
      dataSource:ds,
      searchString:'',
      search_result:PropTypes.node,
      test_item:PropTypes.node,
      loaded: false,    
     width: (width / 3),
    height:( width / 3) ,
    backgroundColor:'#ededed',
    marginTop:5,
    marginBottom:5,
    marginRight:5,
    marginLeft:5,
    alignItems:'center',
    borderRadius:10,
    borderColor:'black',
    borderWidth:0.1,

  };

}

fetchDataPhoto() {

    fetch('https://Example.com/..........')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          search_result:responseData,
          'loaded': true

        });

        this.setState({
          dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.search_result),
        });
      })
      .done();

  }


  renderRow(rowData){
    return (
      <View style={{
    width: this.state.width,
    height: this.state.height,

      }}>
              <View style={ styles.s }>

               <Text style={styles.price}>userId:{rowData.userId}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.Itemtitle}>id:{rowData.id}</Text>
              <Text style={[styles.Itemtitle]}>title:{rowData.title}</Text>
              </View>

            </View>
    )
  }


   renderScene(route, nav) {



<ScrollView ref="scrollView" style={{flex: 1, position:'absolute',top:50,left:0,right:0,bottom:50}} >
                {
                    this.state.loaded && 


                <ListView         
             contentContainerStyle={{        
             flex: 1,
             flexDirection: 'row',
             flexWrap: 'wrap',
             justifyContent: 'center',
             alignItems:'center'  
                  }}
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}/>
                }
                </ScrollView>

          // handling event ChangeItemSize, I need different view I writen below.

         <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeItemSize.bind(this)}>
         <View style={[styles.selectedItemView]}>
         <Icon name="cutlery" style={[styles.iconItemSetting,styles.navBarBottomIcon,styles.selectedItem]} />
         </ View>
         </ TouchableOpacity>
   }


    // different view for updating setState Style changing hight and width


 changeItemSize(){
      page+=1
      if(page == 11){
        page = 6;
      }

    switch (page) {  
            case 6:
            this.setState({
        width: width / 3 - 20,
        height: width / 3 - 20,  
           });
            break;
            case 7:

            this.setState({
        width: width / 1,
        height: width / 4 - 20, 

         });
            break;
            case 8:

             this.setState({
             width: width / 1,
        height: width / 3,

     });
            break;
            case 9:

             this.setState({
        width: width / 1,
        height: width / 2,   

            });
            break;
            case 10:

             this.setState({
        width: width / 1,
        height: width / 1.3,
           });
            break;
            default:

             this.setState({
        width: width / 3 - 20,
        height: width / 3 - 20,
           });
            break;
       }


    }
```

Comment: state's key is should not be `String`. It must be `Object`. You should remove quotation mark on `'loaded': true` like `loaded: true`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but I think one of your problems is that the data is not been set into the state?

Try updating the `fetchDataPhoto` method like this:

```
fetchDataPhoto() {
  fetch('https://Example.com/..........')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      this.setState({
        search_result: responseData,
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData),
        loaded: true
      });
  })
  .done();

}
```

The problem is that `setState` runs asynchronously, and by the time you try to get `search_result` it doesn't exist on the state yet, therefore you are getting a `null` value.

Also, you are overwriting `dataSource`, you should define a different name to avoid overwriting it when the data loads.

There are many other things you could improve in your code, but I think with the change I propose you will be able to see the list of items.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. I am new to react, Yes  I have to improve lot more, I updated this. But my issue is that. listview item I have to show different views like grid view , giant view and large item view, changing the height and width of the listview item so I used set state for different views while updating the setState value state is updated with new value but component style is not updating. where I did wrong I didn't get. thanks for your time @Crysfel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by setting state in this way:

```
this.state = {
  ...this.state,
  search_result:responseData,
  'loaded': true
}
```

basically, I'm setting state to a new object, and that's ok and totally works.

Comment: changing the style for list view items I written styling in state, I am using onpress event for separate button for different listview item styles, but when changing the state. state value is changing but not updating in listview item.

 this.state = {
     width: (width / 3),
    height:( width / 3) ,
    backgroundColor:'#ededed',
    marginTop:5,
    marginBottom:5,
    marginRight:5,
    marginLeft:5,
    alignItems:'center',
    borderRadius:10,
    borderColor:'black',
    borderWidth:0.1,

  };

Comment: don't add styles to state. it's not good. change the styles based on state. for example: `let decideStyle = this.state.loaded ? styles.style1 :styles.style2` and then in button add styles like this `style={ss}`

Comment: Thanks for writing me, first time it is working but after changing the state style is not updating,
**
   renderRow(rowData){
     let itemStyleRow = this.state.loadedItemStyle > 7 ? styles.item6 : styles.item7;
    return (
      <View style={[itemStyleRow]}>
            </View>
    )
}  **

Comment: More then 15 listview style is not updating is there any way to refresh the view? @Fatemeh

Comment: same I did what you mention in this comment but it is not working here I am attaching the link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506897/more-then-15-list-view-style-is-not-updating?noredirect=1#comment66332059_39506897]. could you please look on this. what I did wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm not sure I can totally understand, but logging may help you. in the renderRow function, use console.log(itemStyleRow) and see how many times the function is used and whether the style has changed or not. it is possible that for some reason style is not changing as you have predicted