# more then 15 list view style is not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-native

At first time my loadedItemStyle is 6, styles.item6 is working. after updating the state to 7 style is not changing to styles.item7. If list view is less then 15 it is working fine. How could it make it happen.

*in renderScene have a button: changeItemSize() here I am changing state of   loadedItemStyle based on this I am updating style in renderRow listview items*  **it is working when list item is less then 15 otherwise it is not working.**

```
    import React, { Component,PropTypes } from 'react';

    import {
      StyleSheet,
      View,
      Image,
      Navigator,
      TextInput,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Text,
      Dimensions,
      ListView,
      ScrollView,
      TouchableHighlight

    } from 'react-native';

    import GiftedSpinner from 'react-native-gifted-spinner';
    var Icon = require('react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome');
    const logo = require('../../assets/splash-logo.png');
    var width = Dimensions.get('window').width - 20;
    var page = 6;
     var mainRow = [];


    class FeedUserGrid extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
        var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
          rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 != r2
        });
      this.state = {
        ...this.state,
          dataSource:ds,
          searchString:'',
          search_result:PropTypes.node,
          test_item:PropTypes.node,
          loaded: false,
          refreshing:false,

          loadedItemStyle:6,

      };

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
      }



    fetchDataPhoto() {

        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseData) => {
            this.setState({
              search_result:responseData,
              'loaded': true

            });

            this.setState({
              dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.search_result),
            });
          })
          .done();

      }

      fetchData() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseData) => {
            console.log(responseData);


            var limitDataLength = 20;
            //mainRow.push(responseData);

            for(let i=0; i< responseData.length; i++ ){
              if(i  < limitDataLength){
                mainRow.push({

                    userId:responseData[i].userId,
                    id:responseData[i].id,
                    title:responseData[i].title,
              });
              }else if(limitDataLength == i){
                break;
              }

            }
         console.log(mainRow);
            this.setState({
               search_result:responseData,
               dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(mainRow),
              'loaded': true

            });


          })
          .done();

      }

      filterStates(searchText, states) {

        var text = searchText.toLowerCase();
        var rows = [];

        console.log(states);
        console.log(text);


       for (let i=0; i < states.length; i++) {
         var stateName = states[i].title.toLowerCase();
         if(stateName.search(text) !== -1){
             rows.push({

                    userId:states[i].userId,
                    id:states[i].id,
                    title:states[i].title,
              });
         }
       }
           console.log(rows);
        this.setState({
           dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(rows),
           loaded : true,
           reloading:true,


         });
        }


        setSearchText(event){

          var searchText = event.nativeEvent.text;
          this.setState({ searchString: searchText });
          this.filterStates(searchText, this.state.search_result);
           if (searchText === '') {
             this.fetchData();
           }

        }



        renderRow(rowData){
         let itemStyleRow = () => { 

            switch (this.state.loadedItemStyle) {

            case 6:
            return styles.item6;
            break;

            case 7:
            return styles.item7;
            break;

            case 8:
            return styles.item8;
            break;

            case 9:
            return styles.item9;
            break;

            case 10:
            return styles.item10;
            break;

            default:
            return styles.item6;
            break;

          }

       }
        return (
**

    // ----------------------- calling ter itemStyleRow() updating 
      the style but it is not working more then 15 list item if it is less then 15 working fine how to fix this.

**

          <View style={itemStyleRow()}>
                  <View style={ styles.s }>

                   <Text style={styles.price}>userId:{rowData.userId}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.Itemtitle}>id:{rowData.id}</Text>
                  <Text style={[styles.Itemtitle]}>title:{rowData.title}</Text>
                  </View>

                </View>
        )


      }

      render() {

        return (
          <Navigator

              renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
              navigator={this.props.navigator}
              navigationBar={
                <Navigator.NavigationBar style={[styles.NavBar]}
                    routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />

              } 


              />

        );
      }

      configureScene(route, routeStack){

      Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromLeft;

      }



      renderScene(route, nav) {

       return (

    <View style={[styles.container]}>
           <View style={[styles.SearchBar]}>

    <View style={[styles.SearchParent]}>
    <View style={[styles.IconSearchView]}>
    <Icon name="search" style={[styles.IconSearch]} />
    </ View>
        <View style={[styles.input]}>
             <TextInput
             ref='searchString'
             onChange={this.setSearchText.bind(this)}
              value={this.state.searchString}
        style={styles.searchInput}
        placeholder='What Seasonal Food Are You Hungry For?'/>
        </ View>



    </ View>

     </ View>







    <View style={[styles.header_item,styles.GridViewContainer]}>
        {  !this.state.loaded && 
          <GiftedSpinner />
        }
    </View>

                   <ScrollView ref="scrollView" style={{flex: 1, position:'absolute',top:50,left:0,right:0,bottom:50}} >
                    {
                        this.state.loaded && 

                    <ListView
                  refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                    contentContainerStyle={{ 
                 flex: 1,
                 flexDirection: 'row',
                 flexWrap: 'wrap',
                 justifyContent: 'center',
                 alignItems:'center'                
                      }}
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}/>
                    }
                    </ScrollView>




    // -------------  Here changeItemSize() I am changing the setState loadedItemStyle -------------------------------------


           <View style={[styles.BottomBar]}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeItemSize.bind(this)}>
             <View style={[styles.selectedItemView]}>
             <Icon name="cutlery" style={[styles.iconItemSetting,styles.navBarBottomIcon,styles.selectedItem]} />
             </ View>
             </ TouchableOpacity>
           </ View>

    </ View>
        );

          //return <route.component {...route.passProps} navigator={navigator} />





    }


     changeItemSize(){
      page+=1
      if(page == 11){
        page = 6;
      }

          switch (page) {  
            case 6:
            this.setState({
              loadedItemStyle:6,
            }, function() {
              alert(this.state.loadedItemStyle);
            // loadedItem style changed
             });
            break;
            case 7:

            this.setState({
              loadedItemStyle:7,
           }, function() {
            });
            break;
            case 8:

             this.setState({
               loadedItemStyle:8,
           }, function() {
           });
            break;
            case 9:

             this.setState({
              loadedItemStyle:9,
            }, function() {
             });
            break;
            case 10:

             this.setState({
                loadedItemStyle:10,
            }, function() {

             });
            break;
            default:

             this.setState({
               loadedItemStyle:6,

           }, function() {

            });
            break;
          }


     }

    }



    const styles = StyleSheet.create({

      item6:{

        width: width / 3 - 20,
        height: width / 3 - 20,
        backgroundColor:'#ededed',
        marginTop:5,
        marginBottom:5,
        marginRight:10,
        marginLeft:10,
        alignItems:'center',
        borderRadius:10,
        borderColor:'black',
        borderWidth:0.1,
      },
      item7:{

        width: width / 1,
        height: width / 4 - 20,
        backgroundColor:'#ededed',
        marginTop:3,
        marginBottom:3,
        marginRight:10,
        marginLeft:10,
        alignItems:'center',
        borderRadius:10,
        borderColor:'black',
        borderWidth:0.5,
      },
      item8:{
             width: width / 1,
        height: width / 3,
        backgroundColor:'#ededed',
        marginTop:3,
        marginBottom:3,
        marginRight:10,
        marginLeft:10,
        alignItems:'center',
        borderRadius:10,
        borderColor:'black',
        borderWidth:0.5,
      },
      item9:{
        width: width / 1,
        height: width / 2,
        backgroundColor:'#ededed',
        marginTop:3,
        marginBottom:3,
        marginRight:10,
        marginLeft:10,
        alignItems:'center',
        borderRadius:10,
        borderColor:'black',
        borderWidth:0.5,
      },
      item10:{
        width: width / 1,
        height: width / 1.3,
        backgroundColor:'#ededed',
        marginTop:3,
        marginBottom:3,
        marginRight:10,
        marginLeft:10,
        alignItems:'center',
        borderRadius:10,
        borderColor:'black',
        borderWidth:0.5,
      }

    });
    module.exports = FeedUserGrid;
```

Comment: Try changing `<View style={[itemStyleRow]}>` to `<View style={{ ...itemStyleRow }}>` and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for replaying me. it's not working at loading it's giving error like. **In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object.This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant.**

Comment: Change `<View style={[itemStyleRow]}>` to `<View style={ itemStyleRow }>` and let me know if you see any error.

Comment: Now it is working but it is same as first I got, style is not updating in list item,  if list item is  less then 15 items it is updating.

Comment: Can you post the entire code of this component?

Comment: @Random please check one I posted entire code

Comment: What does `page+=1
      if(page == 11){
        page = 6;
      }` achieve in `changeItemSize`? If the page count is > 10, you're resetting it to 6

Comment: @RandomUser Yes you are right. I am resetting it to 6.

Comment: Its little difficult to make sense of this.., anyways could you `console.log('state.dataSource',this.state.dataSource);` in your `renderScene` and let me know the what you see in the log, also do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: @RandomUser I am not getting any error! **I am getting obj:**  `ListViewDataSource {
  _cachedRowCount:60,
  _dataBlob: Object, 
  _dirtyRows: Array[1],
   _dirtySections: Array[1],
    _cachedRowCount: 20, 
    rowIdentities: Array[1],
    defaultGetRowData( dataBlob, sectionID, rowID)
_getSectionHeaderData:defaultGetSectionHeaderData( dataBlob, sectionID)
_rowHasChanged:rowHasChanged(r1,r2)
_sectionHeaderHasChanged:()
  }` if I have less then 15 list items renderRow is triggering otherwise it is not.

Comment: The only possibility i can think of is, its its rendering but you cannot see it as you will have to scroll to see it, Try adding `renderScrollComponent` and see if you can see all the items.

Comment: Example: import `RecyclerViewBackedScrollView` from `react-native` and in `ListView`, add `renderScrollComponent={props => <RecyclerViewBackedScrollView {...props} />}`

Comment: Also try adding `height` on `ListView` to some fixed value so you can see if other items exists or not.